# Login fails after new user registration | Weblogic security

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic9.x

My application is deployed on `Weblogic` and I'm extending Unified User Profile(UUP) from `Weblogic API` for new user registration into the portal but I'm facing an issue where after completion of user registration, user gets redirected to login page instead of landing page.

Hereby I'm attaching my implementation details and exception logs:

I'm using `ServletAuthentication.login();` each time a user logs in

```
ProfileWrapper profile = null;

      try {
                profile = ProfileFactory.getProfile((String) userAttributes.get(USERNAME), null);
            }catch(RemoteException rex){
                logger.error("RemoteException while setting profile: " + (String)userAttributes.get(USERNAME), rex);
                createErrorResponse(request, response,
                        REQUEST_FAILED, rex.getMessage(), rex
                                .getClass().getCanonicalName(),HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }catch(ProfileNotFoundException pex){
                logger.error("ProfileNotFoundException while setting profile: " + (String)userAttributes.get(USERNAME),pex);
                createErrorResponse(request, response,
                        REQUEST_FAILED, pex.getMessage(), pex
                                .getClass().getCanonicalName(),HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
```

**Error logs:**

```
2017-06-22 21:06:49,747 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR UserLoginServlet     - ProfileNotFoundException while setting profile: ************@********.com
com.bea.p13n.usermgmt.profile.ProfileNotFoundException: ************@********.com
    at com.bea.p13n.usermgmt.profile.internal.PhantomProfileWrapperImpl.validateProfile(PhantomProfileWrapperImpl.java:406)
    at com.bea.p13n.usermgmt.profile.ProfileFactory.getProfile(ProfileFactory.java:205)
    at com.bea.p13n.usermgmt.profile.ProfileFactory.getProfile(ProfileFactory.java:122)
    at com.bea.p13n.usermgmt.profile.ProfileFactory.getProfile(ProfileFactory.java:99)
    at nz.co.vodafone.portal.utility.security.UserLoginServlet.authenticateNFetchProfile(Use
```

**JDK Version:** 6
**Weblogic Version:** WebLogic Server 9.2(deprecated)

Need help from Weblogic(9.2) experts. Help would be highly appreciated.

**PS:** I'm aware that this Oracle is no more supporting Weblogic 9.2 but I cant change version..

Googled out and found that this is product issue. Need to confirm.